# Undefined Error Within a Promise Fulfilled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, es6-promise

I am calling the openweathermap api to retrieve the weather in `higher-order` component, which then renders the 'Main' component. However, after the success of ajax call, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: _getWeather2.default(...) is undefined
```

Code:

**MainContainer.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import getWeather from "../action/getWeather";
import Main from "./Main";

const MainContainer = () => {
// the error is somewhere related to this component
    var weather = getWeather( "london", "uk" )
        .then(( data ) => {
            console.log( "data in maincontainer is...", data );
            return <Main />;
        });
}

export default MainContainer;
```

**getWeather.js:**

```
const getWeather = ( city, country ) => {
    let queryPath = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${ city },${ country }&APPID=${ inserytKey }&mode=json`
    console.log( "queryPath is...", queryPath );
    fetch( queryPath )
        .then(( response ) => response.json( ))
        .then(( data ) => {
            console.log( "data is...", data );
            return data;
        })
        .catch(( err ) => {
            console.log( err );
        })
};

export default getWeather;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: getWeather is not returning a promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getWeather()` function doesn't return anything. You need to return the promise produced by the promise chain you have there.

Your function is also currently swallowing errors, so I've added a `throw err` to your `.catch` handler:

```
const getWeather = ( city, country ) => {
    let queryPath = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${ city },${ country }&APPID=${ inserytKey }&mode=json`
    console.log( "queryPath is...", queryPath );

    return fetch( queryPath )
        .then(( response ) => response.json( ))
        .then(( data ) => {
            console.log( "data is...", data );
            return data;
        })
        .catch(( err ) => {
            console.log( err );
            throw err;
        })
};
```

If you decide you don't need that `console.log` to log the `data` value, you can remove the second `.then`. Likewise for the `.catch()`:

```
const getWeather = ( city, country ) => {
    let queryPath = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${ city },${ country }&APPID=${ inserytKey }&mode=json`
    console.log( "queryPath is...", queryPath );

    return fetch( queryPath )
        .then(( response ) => response.json( ));
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this was an eye opener. I still do not feel comfortable with promises and will keep practicing & delving deeper into it. Voted & accepted with an extra topping of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

getWeather needs to return a promise.

```
const getWeather = ( city, country ) => {
    let queryPath = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${ city },${ country }&APPID=${ inserytKey }&mode=json`
    console.log( "queryPath is...", queryPath );
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch( queryPath )
            .then(( response ) => response.json( ))
            .then(( data ) => {
                console.log( "data is...", data );
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch(( err ) => {
                reject(err);
                console.log( err );
            })
    })
};

export default getWeather;
```

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)